# AppCompatButton has no ripple affect on lollipop devices

Tags: java, android

I have made an AppCompat button like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/categoryButton"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    style="@style/GenericButtonStyle"/>
```

And it is styled as this:

v21:

```
<style name="GenericButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/color_accent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:background">@color/color_accent</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">2dp</item>
</style>
```

v16: (All the rest - minimum being Android 4.0)

```
<style name="GenericButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I am getting the desire background and touch feedback but there is no ripple affect on Lollipop+ devices. I want normal touch feedback on pre-lollipop devices and the ripple affect on lollipop devices. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic ripple setup**

Ripples contained within the view.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Ripples that extend beyond the view's bounds:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```